# User acceptance rate is incorrect?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, accept-rate

I noticed that my acceptance rate had dipped a bit low,

[image]

so I went to my [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82156/emmby?tab=questions) to try to see if there were any more answers I could accept.

Going through all four pages of questions (100 questions), I only found 7 that were not green.  93 out of 100 should be a 93% acceptance rate, not 66%.

What am I missing?

Comment: looks like `(71/107)*100 == 66.335` which is `~66`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I only found 7 that were not green.

The green means the question has an answer (or several).

For questions where you have accepted an answer, the answer count is yellow as in the two lower questions.

[image]

I have counted more than 10 of your questions where there was an answer with a white answer count (like the topmost, so no accepted answer) before I stopped.

Visiting your answered questions to see whether an answer is worthy of acceptance is good, but you shouldn't worry too much about your accept rate, 66% is fine.

Comment: Ah, that must be it then.  Thanks for clearing that up